# Superclass's default no argument constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

In java tutorials,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors. This default constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the superclass. In this situation, the compiler will complain if the superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor so you must verify that it does. If your class has no explicit superclass, then it has an implicit superclass of Object, which does have a no-argument constructor.

Can anyone provide me with an example where is this compile error possible?

Comment: Didn't somebody ask this very question earlier today?

Comment: This question has been asked many times with the same answers. Once such example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286348/how-can-a-java-class-have-no-no-arg-constructor. My suggestion, please do a quick google search before posting questions. You would get tons of answers faster and reduce dupes here.

Comment: @Sebastian: Yes one was asked and deleted 4 hours ago. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087267/superclasss-no-argument-default-constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class A
{
    int a;
    A(int a)
    {
        this.a=a;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    B(int a)
    {
        this.a=a;
    }
}

class C 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        B obj=new B(20);
        System.out.println("a = "+obj.a);
    }
}
```

```
Error:Constructor A in class A cannot be applied to given types;
{
^
required: int
found:no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class A
{
    public A(int n)
    {

    }
}

class B extends A
{

}
```

Comment: And yes SO I'm a humain being! :)

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a `Super` class

```
class Super {

 // no constructor
 // Java compiler will assign a default constructor
 // Super () {} 

}
```

and a `Child` class

```
class Child extends Super {

      public Child() {
          //super(); --> this statement will be inserted by default by Java compiler, even though you don't put it in your code
      }

}
```

And If `Super` is like this

```
class Super {

  Super(int a) {
    // Now this is the only constructor Super class has
    // Java doesn't insert a default constructor now..
  }

}
```

`Child` cannot have no argument constructor, because `Super` doesn't have it anymore

```
class `Child` {

  Child() {
     // super();
     //this will be error since there is no "no-argument" constructor in Super
  }

}
```

Comment: There is a case, however, when the `Child` class in this case can have a default constructor. This is when the no-arg constructor makes a call to `super()` with an argument, e.g. `super(0)` or `super(5)`.